# bluebirdjs coroutine error handling (browser)

Tags: javascript, error-handling, bluebird, coroutine

How am I supposed handle errors in bluebird coroutines?

I've used co in node for a while which has a great catch function.

```
co(function*() {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // whatever stuff
    });

}).catch(function(err) {console.error(error.stack)});
```

But with bluebird on the browser/client side it's a total nightmare. There's no catch function and the errors I am getting back – if at all – are either anonymous or unhandled which is total brainf...

I've checked on the web site of bluebirdjs and there was discussion going on about how to handle errors a few months ago. Evenually someone wrote:

> There should be a better example highlighting the benefits of using try, catch and finally inside coroutine.

http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

I mean: try, catch finally nested in the coroutine? I admit, I've even been following that advice for a couple of routines, but I just doesn't seem to be right. The whole point of Promises and coroutines is to get rid of ugly excessive nesting, which the callbacks have created and now what? Here we go again?

Please, if anyone has an idea how this bluebirdjs error mayhem can be turned into a better solution, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: `Promise.coroutine` == `co.wrap`. Both return functions that return promises which have `catch` methods.

Comment: @Bergi Stupid me, you are right. I tried to set catch before invokation like this 

*Promise.coroutine(/* generator stuff */).catch(handler)*

instead of

*Promise.coroutine(/* generator stuff */).().catch(handler)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that `co` is a bluebird `Promise.coroutine` it will automatically propagate errors and log unhandled rejections.

Unhandled errors are logged. You can handle errors like:

```
Promise.coroutine(function*() { 
    try {
       doSomething();
       yield doSomethingAsync();
    } catch (e) {
       // handle error
    }
})();
```

Comment: Of course, your answer is right. But the thing is: it should not be like that. I errors are already caught in doSomethingAsync then there shouldn't have to be another try/catch block in the coroutine.

Comment: Right, and it indeed works that way - have you experienced something different?